# How to increase PHPStorm clipboard history size?

Tags: phpstorm

By default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> brings up a window with 5 last items copied, is there a way to increase that number?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Editor` | **Maximum number of contents to keep in clipboard**.

[image: clipboard limit]

Comment: For those from 2017: `File` | `Settings...` | `Editor` | `General`  look there for `Limits` section => Maximum number of contents to keep in clipboard

Answer (score 0):

At the time of 2021 y.

You should increase it from `Registry`.

1. Press `Shift` + `Shift`
2. Input `clipboard.history.max.items`
3. Increase `Value` column

[Registry view pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHo5L.png)